# How do I use the same firebase database in multiple HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app that has a dashboard, this dashboard links to different HTML pages that do different stuff that requires updating my firebase database, with a single page app I can do this without issue, issue comes when I try to do it with multiple pages

When I try to connect to the database from dashboard_2.html it says that the app already exists (because I already called it from index.html from database.js), if I remove the configuration part from the js file and just let the modify part it says that no firebase app has been created.

index.html

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.6.1/firebase-ui-auth__es.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.6.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>



    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="js/database.js"></script>

</head>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">

    <!-- User admining -->
    <li><a href="dashboard_2.html">users</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

database.js, where I connect to firebase

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBWVRTc7stMysJVw4rjvzzn5-FnvMAE8_8",
  authDomain: "proveneet.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://proveneet.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "proveneet",
  storageBucket: "proveneet.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "37090380224",
  appId: "1:37090380224:web:a9e4c49d1e4b80bf"
};
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  var database = firebase.database();
```

dashboard_2.html

```
 <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.6.1/firebase-ui-auth__es.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.6.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
        <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
        <!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>


        <!-- Firebase -->
        <script src="js/manageusers.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">

            <li class="active"><a href="dashboard_2.html">users</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</div>



<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right" type="submit" id="addusr">Next</button>
```

manageusers.js, this is where i want to add info to the database

```
var connect = database.ref("/users");
```

If i copy what it is in database.js to manageusers.js and add var connect = database.ref("/users"); it tells me that the app already exists, if I don't it tells me that no firebase app was created, I want to use the same firebase database in both pages but I cannot do it this way, is there any way I can?

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent your app from initializing again.

Change `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` to

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

Comment: you just saved me a huge headache!

Answer (score 0):

i think  is normal , Firebase keeps the connection  of the user until he/she logout.  what you can do it connect and then pass the data to other pages.
you can  use the local storage to keep some basic information you may one to pass between the pages.

Read more below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage